# Laravel 5.3 "Job" doesn't work

Tags: laravel-5.3

I have setup this Notification:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;


use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

class Published extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->from('support@ober24.de')
                    ->greeting('Hallo!')
                    ->subject('Neue Anfrage @ Ober24.de')
                    ->line('Wir haben ein neues Event für Sie verfügbar.')
                    ->action('Neues Event', 'http://localhost:8000/articles');
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

and in my QueuesController i have this

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class QueuesController extends Controller
{


    public function index() {


    $users = \App\User::all();

        foreach ($users as $user) {
            dispatch(new \App\Jobs\SendNewArticleNotification); 
        }

    }
}
```

I just don't know what to put in my SendNewArticleNotification Job handle method so that all the users get an email....

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class SendNewArticleNotification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {

       ??????????????????????

    }
}
```

$user->notify(new \App\Notifications\Published());

this line is to send only one email but it fails, probably because the $user variable is not defined.

How to transfer the $user variable from controller to Job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i have finally fixed this, so if anyone needs it here is the solution:

in controller, the `dispatch(new SendArticleNotification)` needs to have the $user variable in it so that it can be passed to the job like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Jobs\SendNewArticleNotification;
use App\Http\Requests;

class QueuesController extends Controller
{


    public function notifyAllUsers() {

        $users = \App\User::all();

        foreach ($users as $user) {
            dispatch(new SendNewArticleNotification($user));
        }

    }
}
```

And then in Job class the $user variable just needs to be instantiated/constructed like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Notifications\Published;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class SendNewArticleNotification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $user;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($user)
    {

        $this->user = $user;

    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {


        $this->user->notify(new Published());

    }
}
```